# Why do most theories about derivatives use closed/open intervals?

Tags: calculus

How come most theories like the Mean Value Theorem, Intermediate Value Theorem, Bounded Derivative Theorem, all start with if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, and differentiable on $(a, b)$?

Comment: Because they use those assumptions in the proof?

Comment: short version is that differentiability is stronger than continuity. So if you impose $f$ be differentiable on $[a,b]$, then those theorems still holds. But using a weaker assumption that $f$ may be non-differentiable at the end points, the theorem is true for larger (albeit slightly) class of functions.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption of continuity on closed interval is a key in those theorems which you cite. Continuity on a closed interval has far reaching /important and interesting consequences which can't be guaranteed if the intervals are open. This is linked very tightly to the completeness property of the real numbers.

For differentiability assumption in these theorems it does not matter whether the intervals used are closed or open and thus the weaker assumption of open intervals is chosen here.

You will be in a much better position to appreciate these matters if you get familiar with the proofs of the theorems you have mentioned.